# Wpd scripting help

Tags: javascript, powershell, wpd

I need a small script, preferably powershell or js, to automaticly change some values on a camera, using to "Windows Portable Devices".
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hm..that is pretty broad. Can you give us some specifics on what you want to change?

Anyway, here is a pointer to the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389297(v=VS.85).aspx

The above link has some good examples in JS.

Comment: I would like to change the Exposure Compensation Setting on the camera

Comment: Wow! I have a Canon 550D. I don't see how I can access that when I connect the camera to my system. Good one to explore though! I may eventually write a module if I find it!